# Couchbase Server 5.0.1 session provider

Tags: session, couchbase

hi i tried to upgrade couchbase to 5.0.1 
and my sessionstate provider stop working 
i uses the same config as for 4.5.1 any idea what need to be changed 
i use the CouchbaseNetClient -Pre

```
<buckets>
      <add name="sessions" password="mypass" />
</buckets>

 <sessionState customProvider="couchbase-session" mode="Custom">
      <providers>
        <add name="couchbase-session" type="Couchbase.AspNet.SessionState.CouchbaseSessionStateProvider, Couchbase.AspNet" bucket="sessions" exclusiveAccess="false" />
      </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because authentication works differently in 5.0. Buckets no longer have passwords. Instead you have users which have roles.

Check out the SessionState project on github for more info: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-aspnet/blob/3.0/examples/SessionStateExample/Web.config

Here's a relevant snippet from https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-aspnet/blob/3.0/examples/SessionStateExample/Web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <sessionState customProvider="Couchbase" mode="Custom">
      <providers>
        <add name="Couchbase"
             timeout="1"
             type="Couchbase.AspNet.Session.CouchbaseSessionStateProvider, Couchbase.AspNet"
             username="Administrator"
             password="password"
             bucket="default"
             bootstrapStrategy="inline"
             servers="http://10.111.170.101:8091; http://10.111.170.102:8091"
             useSsl="false"
             prefix="app1"
             maxPoolSize="10"
             minPoolSize="1"
             operationLifespan="2500"
             sendTimeout="15000"
             connectTimeout="1000"
             throwOnError="false"/>
      </providers>
```